# Wrapping JFrame List

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a Java GUI (please refrain from commenting on that aspect) and I'm using a `List()` to display strings, how do I make that list a certain width and make the text wrap if it goes outside that constraint? Right now my code is pretty simple:

```
List list = new List();
list.add(myString);
contentPane.add(list, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

`myString` will be an `ArrayList` of strings.

On a somewhat related note, to build this GUI I'm using the Google project Eclipse feature and like most Java GUI builders it's pretty difficult to work with. I have working code right now that I just want to make a GUI for. I essentially want to display the building of a Binary Tree. Are there any GUI builders or methods that are easier to work with? I know I'm presenting two separate questions, but I'll continue using this method if I have to.

Comment: What is `List` --> `java.awt.List`?

Comment: please refrain from commenting on that aspect ---> :-) post an SSCCE short, runnable, compilable otherwise you could be the target for nice jokes

Comment: How do you define your string width constraint? Characters? Inches? Centimeters?

Comment: @nachokk yes it's `java.awt.List`

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  (dismissive) Peh!  You kids and your rock'em sock'em technology.  The Cubit is the unit of measurement ***I'd*** use.  It has the advantage that a) everyone has the measure (length of forearm) 'on their persons' at all times, but even better, b) you could send a man, a boy and a young woman for the same measurement and get 3 different values.  Choice!  ;)

Comment: Consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating your problem. You'll get better answer in this way, less guessing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to encapsulate your strings into a model class.

Here's one way to create a model class.

```
public class BreakableString {

    private String  string;

    public BreakableString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int maxWidth = 80;
        String s = string;

        while (s.length() > maxWidth) {
            String t = getStringPart(s, maxWidth);
            builder.append(t);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            s = s.substring(t.length());
        }

        builder.append(s);

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String getStringPart(String s, int maxWidth) {
        String t = s.substring(0, maxWidth);
        int ePos = t.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (ePos > 0) {
            return t.substring(0, ePos);
        } else {
            return t;
        }
    }

}
```

Next, you create a DefaultListModel of BreakableString.  You use the DefaultListModel to construct your JList.

If this doesn't work, you can create multiple JTextAreas on a JPanel.  You enclose the JPanel with a JScrollPane.